# Anaconda does not start

Tags: python, anaconda

I am a new user, and I do not have much knowledge regarding this world. I have Windows 8.1. I have installed Python version 3.7 for Windows from Anaconda official site.
When running Anaconda Navigator it fails at the stage of loading environments.
Below I detail:

```
C:\Users\Nicolás>anaconda-navigator
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Nicolás\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\widgets\
main_window.py", line 541, in setup
    self.post_setup(conda_data=conda_data)
  File "C:\Users\Nicolás\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\widgets\
main_window.py", line 582, in post_setup
    self.tab_environments.setup(conda_data)
  File "C:\Users\Nicolás\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\widgets\
tabs\environments.py", line 158, in setup
    self.set_packages(packages)
  File "C:\Users\Nicolás\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\widgets\
tabs\environments.py", line 185, in set_packages
    packages, prefix=self.current_prefix, blacklist=self.BLACKLIST
  File "C:\Users\Nicolás\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\api\anac
onda_api.py", line 657, in process_packages
    worker = self._conda_api.pip_list(prefix=prefix)
  File "C:\Users\Nicolás\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\api\cond
a_api.py", line 1616, in pip_list
    sp_dir = sp_dir.decode()
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe1 in position 14: invalid
 continuation byte
```

In case someone had the same problem, I tell you that my solution was to reinstall the program in another folder in which the name does not have special characters.

Comment: Can you run the navigator application using the shortcut/icon?

Comment: Yes, but it reaches the same instance.

Answer (score 1):

First option is to reinstall the Anaconda installer file or if any file is missing, redownload the software.

Another option is to download and install the smaller Miniconda (under 60MB) and then use the command

> conda install anaconda

to download and install all the remaining packages in Anaconda. If the package downloads are interrupted, just run

> conda install anaconda

again. Conda only downloads the packages that were not finished in any previous attempts.

Comment: It is not solved. with the first option the error message is the same. With the second option, I transcribe below the error:

Comment: ´InvalidArchiveError("Error with archive C:\\Users\\Nicolás\\anaconda3\\pkgs\\ana
conda-custom-py37_1o8x4go00\\info-anaconda-custom-py37_1.tar.zst.  You probably
need to delete and re-download or re-create this file.  Message from libarchive
was:\n\nFailed to open 'C:\\Users\\Nicolás\\anaconda3\\pkgs\\anaconda-custom-py3
7_1o8x4go00\\info-anaconda-custom-py37_1.tar.zst'")´

Comment: and so with multiple files